# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 - Can't set date to values between 0 and 14400000

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, date, momentjs

I'm using working with a javascript UI that includes [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).  The data uses '0' as a special flag which gets assigned to the UI.  I'm finding that trying to set the value of the field to 0 is not working, and on further investigation, it stretches to the point where it works at 14400000 but not at 13999999.  What am I doing wrong, or what can I do differently to set the value to 0?

HTML:

```
<h1>Demo</h1>
<form class="form-group" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="enddate">End Date</label>
      <div class='input-group date' id='enddate'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="zeroButton">Set Zero</button>
  <button id="grossButton">Set Gross</button>
  <button id="grosslessButton">Set Grossless</button>
  <button id="todayButton">Set Today</button>

  </button>
  </button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#enddate").datetimepicker();

  $("#zeroButton").click(function() {
    // set to Jan 1, 1970
    $("#enddate").data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date(0));
  });
  $("#grossButton").click(function() {
    // set to Jan 1, 1970
    $("#enddate").data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date(14400000));
  });
  $("#grosslessButton").click(function() {
    // set to Jan 1, 1970
    $("#enddate").data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date(14399999));
  });
  $("#todayButton").click(function() {
    // set to Jan 1, 1970
    $("#enddate").data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date());
  });
});
```

Check out the [working version on the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/xbbdcpcq/).

Comment: I tested: `var zeroDate = new Date(0);` and the result is: `Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)` since this date is less than **January 1, 1970**  maybe It doesn't work because isn't recongnized as a valid date (by the Datepicker v4) control you're using.

Comment: With Date(0) are you trying to get something like 01/01/0001?

Comment: Your code seems fine, I fear that is a bug in the last version of the datetimepicker, indeed, everything works fine with version `4.17.37`.

Comment: I switched to using moment, and it appears to work:
https://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/xbbdcpcq/11/

Comment: @Luke Becker No - Date(0) should give the epoch (Jan 1, 1970).  The trick was that I didn't control the fact that the field was using 0 value for a flag.  I tried doing a swap on load to set it to max javascript date, but jquery and moment really hate big dates.  Ooo maybe the problem would be fixed by not using the Date.

Comment: @Mauricio—that result is consistent since the epoch is 00:00:00UTC+0000 and you are UTC-0500, so 5 hours before the epoch is 19:00 on 31 Dec 1969. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker uses the moment library.  Pass in a moment object instead of a date object:

```
  $("#zeroButton").click(function() {
    // set to Jan 1, 1970
    $("#enddate").data("DateTimePicker").date(moment(0));
  });
```